# How to get SELinux to prevent Apache/HTTPD from reading specific files

Tags: apache-httpd, selinux

What am I missing with SELinux? I thought it was supposed to be another layer of security but I built a web page vulnerable to command injection and it can basically traverse most of my file system.

I thought SELinux was suppose to block httpd from even reading arbitrary files. I'm specifically worried about an attacker reading the /etc/passwd file. I know Dan Walsh mentioned that (http://danwalsh.livejournal.com/56760.html?thread=335032).

Other than the regular Discretionary Access Controls, is there a way to block this through SELinux? Would I have to build my own policy? SELinux is in Enforcing mode.

Comment: Although there are security implications, you're asking a OS-specific configuration implementation, which is better suited to one of the other forums.